# Type 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
static CollectionReference doses =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Doses');
  void setDoseDetails(
      TextEditingController endController,
      TextEditingController startController,
      TextEditingController doseController,
      int noPills,
      int doseRep) {
    var dose =
        doses.where('userID', isEqualTo: Auth().uID).get() as DocumentSnapshot;
    Map<String, dynamic> userData = dose as Map<String, dynamic>;
    endController.text = userData['endDate'];
    startController.text = userData['startDate'];
    noPills = userData['noPills'];
    doseController.text = userData['doseVal'];
    doseRep = userData["doseRep"];
  }
```

I'm trying to retrieve data from Firebase using this code and it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the return type of the `get()` method that you are trying to call in `doses.where('userID', isEqualTo: Auth().uID).get()` it is `Future<QuerySnapshot<T>>`. There are two problems in your approach:

1. You are not awaiting the result of `doses.where('userID', isEqualTo: Auth().uID).get()`.
2. You are forcefully type-casting a QuerySnapshot into a DocumentSnapshot. If `doses.where('userID', isEqualTo: Auth().uID).get()` after awaiting, returns a QuerySnapshot, the variable holding that value should also be of the type QuerySnapshot.

Here is what you can do instead:

```
  static CollectionReference doses =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Doses');
  Future<void> setDoseDetails(
      TextEditingController endController,
      TextEditingController startController,
      TextEditingController doseController,
      int noPills,
      int doseRep) async {
    QuerySnapshot dose =
        await doses.where('userID', isEqualTo: Auth().uID).get();
    Map<String, dynamic> userData = dose as Map<String, dynamic>;
    endController.text = userData['endDate'];
    startController.text = userData['startDate'];
    noPills = userData['noPills'];
    doseController.text = userData['doseVal'];
    doseRep = userData["doseRep"];
  }
```

If you notice in the solution above,

1. I have changed the return type of `setDoseDetails` because it can't be just `void` and has to be `Future<void>` because you are dealing with futures.
2. I have put an `await` keyword in front of the `doses.where('userID', isEqualTo: Auth().uID).get()`. This will allow the response to return and be assigned to the variable `dose`.

To read more about futures I would suggest going through https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

**This might work for you:**

```
var dose =
        await doses.where('userID', isEqualTo: Auth().uID).get();
    var userData = dose.docs.first.data();
    endController.text = userData['endDate'];
    startController.text = userData['startDate'];
    noPills = userData['noPills'];
    doseController.text = userData['doseVal'];
    doseRep = userData["doseRep"];
```

Comment: By using `var userData = dose.docs.first.data();` in your code, you are only taking the first element from all the doses that meet the condition mentioned in your `.where`. This might cause is loss of data or a feature not working properly. If your requirement is just to use the first returning data, then this might work.

Comment: He needs to access only one document, its obvious I believe